# Angular2 - Dynamic component loading with animation

Tags: angular, ng-animate, angular2-components

I'me using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) in order to load components dynamically.
I'm trying to add sliding/fade animation while changing between components.
Does anyone has idea how can I achieve this with the new Angular2 animation?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html ?

Comment: You can try to figure out how animation is done for the router. The router-outlet uses the same method to add components as explained in the thread you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried injecting (from angular2/core)?

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer) { ... }
```

Then later in your code using:

```
this.renderer.animate(freshComponent.location, ..., ..., 0..1, 0..1, '');
```